# What is $\gtrless$?

Tags: notation

I'm reading Papadimitriou & Steiglitz's *Combinatorial Optimization* and came across notation I'd never seen before and don't know what it means. The $\LaTeX$ markup for it is `\gtrless` ($\gtrless$), which took me quite a while to find.

It arises in the formulation of general linear programs in terms of the constraints on the variables:

$$
x_j \geq 0 \;\; j \in N\\
x_j \gtrless 0 \;\; j \in \bar{N}
$$

It's not "not equals" because there's places in the text where the authors say $x$ can be zero.

Comment: maybe it's `more or less`...

Comment: Maybe there are two cases ... and also two choices somewhere else as well.  Top choice goes with top choice, bottom choice goes with bottom choice.

Comment: According to this blog entry (http://jingjinyu.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/concise-introduction-to-the-simplex-algorithm/), which quotes the same section of the same text, it just means "can be any real number".

Comment: And such variables can be eliminated by letting $x_j=x_j'-x_j''$ with $x_j'\ge 0$ and $x_j''\ge 0$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx That's a great link! Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this blog entry ([jingjinyu.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/…](http://jingjinyu.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/concise-introduction-to-the-simplex-algorithm/)), which quotes the same section of the same text, saying that $x_j \gtrless 0$ just means that $x_j$ can be any real number.  And as pointed out in the text, such variables can be eliminated by introducing two non-negative auxiliary variables: $x_j=x_j'-x_j''$ with $x_j'\ge 0$ and $x_j''\ge 0$.