# Double inequality $\lessgtr$ use?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, analysis, notation

I have seen things like `\lessgtr` $\lessgtr$ (less on top, greater on bottom;) being used in paper. Can someone give me an example of how a double inequality is used?

Comment: When I have seen this, it's used in a similar way as $\pm$ and $\mp$, where the two "tops" correspond and the two "bottoms" correspond.

Comment: Like, can you give me a specific example?

Comment: As for "*I am not too sure how to type math formulas here*"... see the [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  All you need to do for yours here is simply enclose it in dollar signs., `$\lessgtr$` produces $\lessgtr$.

Comment: @JMoravitz got it, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is $\gtrless$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608454/what-is-gtrless)

Comment: For example, we have $a\lessgtr b\iff -a\gtrless -b$.

Comment: @JMoravitz that’s one example, I may need to see more examples so I can get a better idea of how it’s used

Comment: @Berci well that’s a very simple example. I was looking for a more concrete example that is commonly used in “common” mathematics like trig, calculus, linear algebra, etc

Comment: In my experience this symbol is *not* "*commonly used*" in "*common*" mathematics...

Comment: It should be clear in context.  I'd interpret $a \lessgtr b$ to mean "either $a < b$ or $a > b$ but we don't know which".  This could  be useful for proving a statement such as "If $0 < a <b$ then $\sqrt{a}< \sqrt{b}$".  Proof: $\sqrt{a}\lessgtr \sqrt{b}\implies a=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{a}\lessgtr\sqrt{b} \lessgtr \sqrt{b}\sqrt{b}=b\implies a\lessgtr b$.  As we know $a < b$ it must be $\sqrt{a}<\sqrt{b}$".  We can do multiple cases at once when the logic is the same.